# Failed to packaging ios app

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova, cocoapods

I tried to package my application but I am stuck here. When I call `pod install` the result is:

```
The `MY APP [Debug]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`  
build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'.   
This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation.
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Go to your target *Build Settings -> Other linker flags -> double click . Add $(inherited)* to a new line.

Comment: thank you  Durai Amuthan.H, I will try this